# How can I manipulate a date field in an aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to set the time from a Date field to the start of the day

```
function getDate(date){ return new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), 
date.getDate(), 0,0,0); }
...
{"$project" : {
    "_id"   : getDate("$dt"),
...
```

- If I send `"$dt"` I get `TypeError: date.getYear is not a function` as I'm passing a string,
- If remove the quotation marks, I get `Error: "$dt is not defined"`,
- but if I set `"$dt"` as value for `"_id"` I get a correct ISO Date.

So how do I pass the date object to the function?

Comment: There is no `getYear` method on a string...

Comment: I think you are looking for [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) here. What is confusing you I think is something like `{ "$gt": new Date() }` does not actually get sent to the server, but rather the "value" gets returned "before" the request is sent to the server, and then used. You cannot send JavaScript functions into an aggregation pipeline, or query. With the exception of `$where`, but in fact that is actually sending a "string".

Comment: @AndrewLi How do I pass the date object to the function then? If I remove the quotation marks, I get the error "$dt is not defined", but if I set "$dt" as value for "_id" I get a correct ISO Date.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's aggregation pipeline does not support JavaScript. To manipulate date values for results in the aggregation pipeline you need to use [Date Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/).

For example :

```
db.date.aggregate([
    { $project: {
         _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y%m%d", date: "$dt" }}
    }}
])
```

Assuming you have a document with a field called `dt` with a date value of `ISODate("2017-07-01T10:01:23.344Z")`, the result would look like:

```
{
  "result": [

    {
      "_id": "20170701"
    }

  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Note: if you have multiple documents for the same day, this approach will create duplicate `_id` values in your results. You may want to project to a different field name or perhaps use a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage instead of `$project` if your intent is to combine values for the same day.